# How can I change the color of each bar in a bar graph using open office?

Tags: openoffice.org

I'm doing an assignment and it involved using color and frequency and I can't figure out how to individually change the color of each bar in a bar graph... Please help me!

Answer (score 5):

By *first click* we can select the chart bars as a whole. Then by performing a *second click* on one of those bars to select one of them we can change the *Format Data Point -> Area* by *right click context menu*:

[image]

There is admittedly a bit of mouse click acrobatics needed but once you have the timing it is pretty fast. This was tested with Libre Office but should also work in Open Office.

Comment: I tried this and it will change the color of the bar, but it changes all of the bars to that color and I need it to be individual colors

Comment: Check that a **single** bar is selected, that's why I included the screenshot. It's a bit tricky to get the two clicks in the right time.